# Populating data in a text box on selection of dropdown using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, database

I am trying to fetch a row on a selection of a particular ID, now when the user selects any value of a drop-down the respective values have to come into text boxes, I am using ajax for the same,I am getting output from my PHP file But they are in array form like `("rahul", "9594233709")`. When I am trying to put them in there respective fields I am not able to do it.

Here is my complete code. I am trying to fetch a row on a selection of a particular ID, now when the user selects any value of a drop-down the respective values have to come into text boxes, I am using ajax for the same,I am getting output from my PHP file But they are in array form like `("rahul", "9594233709")`.

When I am trying to put them in their respective fields I am not able to do it.here is my complete code. I am expecting That location has to move in the location column and mobile has to be in Mobile column, Array is coming perfectly in the front end. For example: `["9594233705", "Gorakhpur"]`

```
<script >
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#reg_number').change(function(){
      var reg_number = $(this).val();
    $.ajax
   ({
   type: "POST",
   url: "details.php",
   data: {post_id:reg_number},
    dataType: "text",
   cache: false,
         success:function(data)
            { 

              $('#u_mobile1').val(data);
            $('#u_location1').val(data);        
         }
   });

   });
    });

</script>
if($_POST['post_id'])
{
$id=$_POST['post_id'];
$sql="SELECT u_mobile,u_location FROM system_users WHERE u_userid=".$id;
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$data = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$u_mobile = $row['u_mobile'];
$u_location = $row['u_location'];
$data[0]=$u_mobile ;
$data[1]= $u_location ;
// $data[] = array('u_mobile' => $u_mobile, 'u_location' => $u_location);
}   echo json_encode($data);
}
<div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="form-group form-group-default required">
      <label>Company Mobile Number:</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" required="" id="u_mobile1" name="u_mobile1" value="" >
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="form-group form-group-default required">
      <label class="">Location</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" required="" id="u_location1" name="u_location1"  value="">
      </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if i didn't get it wrong, you want to parse response Json data and add to inputs.
If this is the case you can use javascript `JSON.parse();` function. Because you getting data as a json list.

```
$.ajax
  ({
  type: "POST",
  url: "details.php",
  data: {post_id:reg_number},
  dataType: "text",
  cache: false,
  success:function(data)
   { 
   var resp = JSON.parse(data);
   document.getElementById("u_mobile").value=resp.u_mobile; 
   document.getElementById("u_location").value=resp.u_location;       
   }
   });
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your revert!But it is not working I do not know why its not populating in input field

Comment: i solved my problem here is the correct way to show fields    document.getElementById("u_mobile").value=resp.u_mobile;

Comment: @javatechie Im happy to your solved problem. I edited my code as `document.getElementById("u_mobile").value=resp.u_mobile;` can you click tick icon of my answer, otherwise the problem appears to be unresolved in the system